# How to access any app context from external service?

Tags: android, service, runnable

My service is external jar library. How do I get any app context inside my `ExecutionCode` runnable? I tried:

```
public class ExecutionCode implements Runnable {
   Context context;
   public ExecutionCode(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
   }
}




public class MyService extends Service {

    Thread testThread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        testThread = new Thread(new ExecutionCode(this.getApplicationContext()), "Bad things happening");
        testThread.start();
    }
```

But I get:

```
07-06 21:50:20.450: E/AndroidRuntime(24959): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not an error because you are using context. This is a threading issue.

I am not sure why this doesn't work, because i think it should since you are creating the Thread in the UI thread...

Try using or looking into the IntentService http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

To create a service that will execute code in a background thread or look into its source to see how Android does it.

Comment: Where could I read about all this stuff? And whats the difference IntentService or Service, both indirect classes of Context.

Comment: You can read the link to the android documentation that i sent you. additionally you can look into the source code of the 2 classes and compare them. Basically the intent service has a handler+looper which creates a queue of tasks that are executed in a background thread one by one, its a level above Service(it extends from Service) so it shows you one way you can use a service.

Comment: Thank you I will try IntentService and also Looper when I get home.